# Turn on experimental decorators during tsc --init?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Is it possible to turn on experimental decorators while running `tsc --init`.  Something like `tsc --init experimentalDecorators=true`?

Comment: I don't think so.  If you intend to file this as a TypeScript suggestion, do think about how it can be done in a generic way and not just for `experimentalDecorators`.

Comment: I'm thinking it's probably better to have it as a snippet in vscode then.  That would get rid of all of the commented out suggestions as well.

Comment: Would be cool if they just switched the warning off though ... do we really need to be warned about decorators?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `tsc --init --experimentalDecorators`